# Send data through a script tag using nodejs vash template

Tags: javascript, node.js, vash

I am new to nodejs. Trying to send some bootstrapped data (logged on user) from a nodejs server using the vash template back to the client with the index page. Need the bootstrapped data on the client to enable/disable certain options based on whether the user is logged in.

The server.js looks like this:

```
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", {
        title: "Page title",
        bootstrappedUser: req.user
    });
});
```

index.vash

```
@html.extend('layout', function(model) {
    @html.block("scripts", function(model){
        @if(model.bootstrappedUser) {
        @{
            var a = model.bootstrappedUser;
        }
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.bootstrappedUser = JSON.stringify(@a);
            </script>
        }
   })
})
```

But this results in an "UncaughtSyntaxError: Unexpected identifier " in the client html on the stringify function below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            window.bootstrappedUser = JSON.stringify([object Object]);
    </script>
```

I tried to look up the [Vash page](https://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash#code-blocks) on Github but there is virtually no documentation on script blocks using vash. Am I using the correct syntax inside 'index.vash' or is there some vash string interpolation that I am missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you must send data by JSON.stringfy(obj) from nodejs then

```
   <script>
       var test = @html.raw(@model)
   </script>
```

mean

server.js

```
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", {
        title: "Page title",
        bootstrappedUser: JSON.stringfy(req.user)
    });
});
```

index.vash

```
@html.extend('layout', function(model) {
    @html.block("scripts", function(model){
        @if(model.bootstrappedUser) {
        @{
            var a = model.bootstrappedUser;
        }
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.bootstrappedUser = @html.raw(a);
            </script>
        }
   })
})
```